# Javascript. Почему таймер обрывается раньше времени?

Tags: javascript, while, функции

Почему таймер обрывается после того как остается 2 секунды до 0?

```html
<script>
function timer(tag, sec) { 

    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = (sec / 60 >> 0) + 'min' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>'; 
    sec -= 1;

    if ((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
        setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, sec); }, 1000);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= "Time is over!";
    }
}
</script> 

<div id="str"></div> 

<input type="button" onclick="timer('str', 5)" value="Нажми меня" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно потому, что вы задали такое поведение в скрипте. Смотрите:

- нажимаем кнопку - вызывается `timer` со значением 5
- в `timer` значение 5 отображается в `div`
- вычитаем 1 от аргумента `sec`
- ставим таймер на перезапуск функции `timer` через 1 секунду, со значением 4
- по срабатыванию `div` устанавливается в 4
- все это повторяется, пока ф-я `timer` не будет вызвана с аргументом 1, в этом случае перезапуска не произойдет, в `div` сначала запишется `1`, и сразу же текст  "Time is over!".

Таким образом таймер срабатывает 4 раза, и каждый раз получаем такие изменения в `div`:

- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1, и сразу же "Time is over!"

---

Немного подредактированный вариант с корректным счетчиком:

```js
function timer(tag, sec) { 
    var el = document.getElementById(tag);
    if (sec > 0) {
        el.innerHTML = (sec / 60 >> 0) + ' min ' + sec % 60 + ' sec'; 
        setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, sec); }, 1000);
        sec -= 1;
    } else {
        el.innerHTML= "Time is over!";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="str"></div> 
<input type="button" onclick="timer('str', 5)" value="Нажми меня" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно `sec -= 1;` перенести куда нужно

```js
function timer(tag, sec) {
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML =
    (sec / 60 >> 0) + ' min ' + sec % 60 + ' sec' + '<br>';
 
    if((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
        setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, sec); }, 1000);
        sec -= 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML= 'Time is over!';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='str'></div>
<input type='button' onclick='timer("str", 5)' value='Нажми меня'>
```